# Minimize count of sequential partitions of a list

Tags: python, list, algorithm, dictionary, sorting

Given a list of integers, I'm trying to count in how many partitions the list must be split such that each sub list follows a sequential order of +1 or -1 (or consist of **just 1 item**). Examples of valid sublists are `[1]`, `[1,2,3,4]`, `[9,8,7]`. Examples of invalid sub lists are `[1,3]`, `[5,4,5]`. Obviously a list can always be split into partitions of just one value each, but the aim is to minimize the number of partitions.

For example:

We can split `[2,1,2,3,3,2,6,7,8]` into these sublists: `[2,1]`, `[2,3]`, `[3,2]`, `[6,7,8]`, for a total number of 4 sublists. Note that the division could also have been `[2]`, `[1,2,3]`, `[3,2]`, `[6,7,8]`, but it doesn't matter for the expected output: 4.

Here are a few more examples:

| input | sublists | expected output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `[1,2,3,2,1,6,8]` | `[1,2,3],[2,1],[6],[8]` or `[1,2],[3,2,1],[6],[8]` | 4 |
| `[1,2,1,1]` | `[1,2],[1],[1]` or `[1],[2,1],[1]` | 3 |
| `[1,2,1]` | `[1,2],[1]` or `[1],[2,1]` | 2 |
| `[1,1,1]` | `[1],[1],[1]` | 3 |
| `[1,2,3,5,2,3]` | `[1,2,3],[5],[2,3]` | 3 |
| `[1,2,3,2,3,2,1]` | `[1,2,3],[2,3],[2,1]` or `[1,2],[3,2],[3,2,1]` | 3 |
| `[]` | - | 0 |
| `[5]` | `[5]` | 1 |
| `[5,5,6,6]` | `[5],[5,6],[6]` | 3 |

So I looked at the differences between two consecutive items in the list:

```
mylist = [2,1,2,3,3,2,6,7,8]
diff = []
for i in range(len(mylist)-1):
    diff.append(mylist[i+1]- mylist[i])
# diff = [-1, 1, 1, 0, -1, 4, 1, 1]
```

There are turning points such as -1 to 1, or 1 to 0, or 0 to -1 (this one does not count), -1 to 4, 4 to 1 (this one doesn't count), so a total of 5 turning points, but two should not be counted: so 3 turning points, which means there are 4 partitions.

I need to count the turning points, but clearly not all of them. How can I differentiate between turning points to only count those that are needed to minimise the number of valid partitions?

Comment: What have you tried so far that doesn't work?

Comment: What about overlaps? What would be the result for [1,2,1]? According to your examples (which do not consider overlaps) the result would be [1,2], total number of 1. But wouldn't [1,2],[2,1], total number of 2 more accurate?

Comment: @treuss, total number should be 2; [1,2], [1] or [1], [2,1]

Comment: Would be very helpful to have all your examples as code, testing a function that does the job ([like this](https://tio.run/##XU7RCoMwDHzvV@TRQh5mnU4Gfon4MLbKCtKWNIL7@i5I3caSp7tL7i6@@Bl800fK@WFniDdixy74VC2J9VWBDFleyUOtFNvECQYYd74aDdZosJE12OEF@wnhrLGoAk4f0AqqvwhbeeiEa4SblJoDgSQi2C3aO4PzsIcdDdK6sAT/9dvFSM5zdZwMxQF/7bA46Jzf)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this and *know* that it works is with dynamic programming.

For each element `x`, you calculate the minimum number of partitions of the list up to `x` such that:

- you could append `x+1` to the last partition
- you could append `x-1` to the last partition

These are easy to calculate for every x if you know the values for the previous one:

```py
def partitionCount(list):
    if len(list) < 2:
        return len(list)

    # minimum # of partitions such that you can append increasing
    partup = 1
    # minimum # of partitions such that you can append decreasing
    partdown = 1

    for i in range(1, len(list)):
        diff = list[i] - list[i-1]
        if diff == 1:
            # partup is unchanged
            partdown = min(partdown,partup) + 1
        elif diff == -1:
            # partdown is unchanged
            partup = min(partdown,partup) + 1
        else:
            partdown = min(partdown,partup) + 1
            partup = partdown
    
    return min(partup, partdown)
```

Comment: Might just be me, but I find this rather puzzling :-). I think mine's easier, but maybe it's DP as well (not posted yet, still waiting for them to add testing code).

Comment: @KellyBundy I suspect your solution uses **two state variables: `count` and `direction`**, where `direction` is ascending, descending, or unspecified. This code is also using **two state variables: `partup` and `partdown`**. It works because at the end of each iteration of the loop: `count = min(partup, partdown)` and `direction = partup - partdown`. This code is less mysterious if you realize that `partup - partdown` is always in `{-1, 0, 1}`, and thus is equivalent to the `direction` state variable. So this is really no different than (what I'm guessing is) your solution, and it's not DP.

Comment: It's almost like that, yes. And yes, I agree yours is similar, but the two separate counts, not that obviously connected and one of them somewhat "pre-counting" future events, make it harder to understand for me. And yes, I'd rather call mine greedy, not DP, although I find the distinction blurry.

Comment: The advantage of framing the solution as a DP solution is that you don't have to prove that the greedy solution works... or, rather, the DP solution *is* the proof that it works.

Comment: Hmm, I disagree. If I change your `+ 1` to `+ 2`, it's still DP, but wrong, so being DP isn't proof.

Comment: Fair enough.  A proof is only proof for people who understand it :)